# MongoDB Arbiter No Respond When Using rs.addArb()

Tags: mongodb

I am setting up a two-replicate and one arbiter setup, the reference is from https://iitbitz.wordpress.com/2016/03/14/how-to-setup-mongodb-replication-using-replica-set-and-arbiters/

Node 1 can speaks with Node 2. Node 1 is the primary and Node 2 is secondary.

I set up Node 3 via the following command

`nohup mongod --port 30000 --dbpath /var/lib/mongo/data --replSet replicaset01 --bind_ip_all &`

However, when I add in Node 3 as arbiter via the command

`rs.add("192.168.60.20:30000", true)`
or
`rs.addArb("192.168.60.20:30000")`,
the mongo freezes (keep runnning but no output).

I
Below is the result of Node 3's Mongo Output

```
auronex@sss-core-api-01-aidtb:~$ cat nohup.out
{"t":{"$date":"2022-05-11T14:22:59.628+08:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":4915701, "ctx":"thread1","msg":"Initialized wire specification","attr":{"spec":{"incomingExternalClient":{"minWireVersion":0,"maxWireVersion":13},"incomingInternalClient":{"minWireVersion":0,"maxWireVersion":13},"outgoing":{"minWireVersion":0,"maxWireVersion":13},"isInternalClient":true}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-05-11T14:22:59.631+08:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23285,   "ctx":"thread1","msg":"Automatically disabling TLS 1.0, to force-enable TLS 1.0 specify --sslDisabledProtocols 'none'"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-05-11T14:22:59.631+08:00"},"s":"W",  "c":"ASIO",     "id":22601,   "ctx":"thread1","msg":"No TransportLayer configured during NetworkInterface startup"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-05-11T14:22:59.631+08:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":4648601, "ctx":"thread1","msg":"Implicit TCP FastOpen unavailable. If TCP FastOpen is required, set tcpFastOpenServer, tcpFastOpenClient, and tcpFastOpenQueueSize."}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-05-11T14:22:59.634+08:00"},"s":"W",  "c":"ASIO",     "id":22601,   "ctx":"thread1","msg":"No TransportLayer configured during NetworkInterface startup"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-05-11T14:22:59.634+08:00"},"s":"W",  "c":"ASIO",     "id":22601,   "ctx":"thread1","msg":"No TransportLayer configured during NetworkInterface startup"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-05-11T14:22:59.634+08:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":5123008, "ctx":"thread1","msg":"Successfully registered PrimaryOnlyService","attr":{"service":"TenantMigrationDonorService","ns":"config.tenantMigrationDonors"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-05-11T14:22:59.634+08:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":5123008, "ctx":"thread1","msg":"Successfully registered PrimaryOnlyService","attr":{"service":"TenantMigrationRecipientService","ns":"config.tenantMigrationRecipients"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-05-11T14:22:59.636+08:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":4615611, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"MongoDB starting","attr":{"pid":876978,"port":30000,"dbPath":"/var/lib/mongo/data","architecture":"64-bit","host":"sss-core-api-01-aidtb"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-05-11T14:22:59.636+08:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23403,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Build Info","attr":{"buildInfo":{"version":"5.0.3","gitVersion":"657fea5a61a74d7a79df7aff8e4bcf0bc742b748","openSSLVersion":"OpenSSL 1.1.1f  31 Mar 2020","modules":[],"allocator":"tcmalloc","environment":{"distmod":"ubuntu2004","distarch":"x86_64","target_arch":"x86_64"}}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-05-11T14:22:59.636+08:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":51765,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Operating System","attr":{"os":{"name":"Ubuntu","version":"20.04"}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-05-11T14:22:59.636+08:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":21951,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Options set by command line","attr":{"options":{"net":{"bindIp":"*","port":30000},"replication":{"replSet":"replicaset01"},"storage":{"dbPath":"/var/lib/mongo/data"}}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-05-11T14:22:59.638+08:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22270,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Storage engine to use detected by data files","attr":{"dbpath":"/var/lib/mongo/data","storageEngine":"wiredTiger"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-05-11T14:22:59.638+08:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22297,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Using the XFS filesystem is strongly recommended with the WiredTiger storage engine. See http://dochub.mongodb.org/core/prodnotes-filesystem","tags":["startupWarnings"]}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-05-11T14:22:59.638+08:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22315,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Opening WiredTiger","attr":{"config":"create,cache_size=7492M,session_max=33000,eviction=(threads_min=4,threads_max=4),config_base=false,statistics=(fast),log=(enabled=true,archive=true,path=journal,compressor=snappy),builtin_extension_config=(zstd=(compression_level=6)),file_manager=(close_idle_time=600,close_scan_interval=10,close_handle_minimum=250),statistics_log=(wait=0),verbose=[recovery_progress,checkpoint_progress,compact_progress],"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-05-11T14:23:00.893+08:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22430,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"WiredTiger message","attr":{"message":"[1652250180:893055][876978:0x7fcd59a13c80], txn-recover: [WT_VERB_RECOVERY_PROGRESS] Recovering log 6 through 7"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-05-11T14:23:00.962+08:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22430,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"WiredTiger message","attr":{"message":"[1652250180:962334][876978:0x7fcd59a13c80], txn-recover: [WT_VERB_RECOVERY_PROGRESS] Recovering log 7 through 7"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-05-11T14:23:01.136+08:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22430,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"WiredTiger message","attr":{"message":"[1652250181:136491][876978:0x7fcd59a13c80], txn-recover: [WT_VERB_RECOVERY | WT_VERB_RECOVERY_PROGRESS] Main recovery loop: starting at 6/18944 to 7/256"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-05-11T14:23:01.289+08:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22430,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"WiredTiger message","attr":{"message":"[1652250181:289612][876978:0x7fcd59a13c80], txn-recover: [WT_VERB_RECOVERY_PROGRESS] Recovering log 6 through 7"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-05-11T14:23:01.404+08:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22430,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"WiredTiger message","attr":{"message":"[1652250181:404495][876978:0x7fcd59a13c80], txn-recover: [WT_VERB_RECOVERY_PROGRESS] Recovering log 7 through 7"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-05-11T14:23:01.486+08:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22430,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"WiredTiger message","attr":{"message":"[1652250181:486927][876978:0x7fcd59a13c80], txn-recover: [WT_VERB_RECOVERY | WT_VERB_RECOVERY_PROGRESS] Set global recovery timestamp: (0, 0)"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-05-11T14:23:01.487+08:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22430,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"WiredTiger message","attr":{"message":"[1652250181:487019][876978:0x7fcd59a13c80], txn-recover: [WT_VERB_RECOVERY | WT_VERB_RECOVERY_PROGRESS] Set global oldest timestamp: (0, 0)"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-05-11T14:23:01.511+08:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22430,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"WiredTiger message","attr":{"message":"[1652250181:511181][876978:0x7fcd59a13c80], WT_SESSION.checkpoint: [WT_VERB_CHECKPOINT_PROGRESS] saving checkpoint snapshot min: 1, snapshot max: 1 snapshot count: 0, oldest timestamp: (0, 0) , meta checkpoint timestamp: (0, 0) base write gen: 443"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-05-11T14:23:01.530+08:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":4795906, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"WiredTiger opened","attr":{"durationMillis":1892}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-05-11T14:23:01.530+08:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"RECOVERY", "id":23987,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"WiredTiger recoveryTimestamp","attr":{"recoveryTimestamp":{"$timestamp":{"t":0,"i":0}}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-05-11T14:23:01.533+08:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":4366408, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"No table logging settings modifications are required for existing WiredTiger tables","attr":{"loggingEnabled":false}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-05-11T14:23:01.535+08:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22262,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Timestamp monitor starting"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-05-11T14:23:01.547+08:00"},"s":"W",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":22120,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Access control is not enabled for the database. Read and write access to data and configuration is unrestricted","tags":["startupWarnings"]}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-05-11T14:23:01.548+08:00"},"s":"W",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":22184,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Soft rlimits for open file descriptors too low","attr":{"currentValue":1024,"recommendedMinimum":64000},"tags":["startupWarnings"]}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-05-11T14:23:01.550+08:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":5071100, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Clearing temp directory"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-05-11T14:23:01.555+08:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":20536,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Flow Control is enabled on this deployment"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-05-11T14:23:01.558+08:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"SHARDING", "id":20997,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Refreshed RWC defaults","attr":{"newDefaults":{}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-05-11T14:23:01.567+08:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"FTDC",     "id":20625,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Initializing full-time diagnostic data capture","attr":{"dataDirectory":"/var/lib/mongo/data/diagnostic.data"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-05-11T14:23:01.582+08:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"-",        "id":4939300, "ctx":"monitoring-keys-for-HMAC","msg":"Failed to refresh key cache","attr":{"error":"ReadConcernMajorityNotAvailableYet: Read concern majority reads are currently not possible.","nextWakeupMillis":200}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-05-11T14:23:01.597+08:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":21311,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Did not find local initialized voted for document at startup"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-05-11T14:23:01.600+08:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":21529,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Initializing rollback ID","attr":{"rbid":1}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-05-11T14:23:01.600+08:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":21313,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Did not find local replica set configuration document at startup","attr":{"error":{"code":47,"codeName":"NoMatchingDocument","errmsg":"Did not find replica set configuration document in local.system.replset"}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-05-11T14:23:01.606+08:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":20714,   "ctx":"LogicalSessionCacheRefresh","msg":"Failed to refresh session cache, will try again at the next refresh interval","attr":{"error":"NotYetInitialized: Replication has not yet been configured"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-05-11T14:23:01.615+08:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":20712,   "ctx":"LogicalSessionCacheReap","msg":"Sessions collection is not set up; waiting until next sessions reap interval","attr":{"error":"NamespaceNotFound: config.system.sessions does not exist"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-05-11T14:23:01.624+08:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":40440,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Starting the TopologyVersionObserver"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-05-11T14:23:01.625+08:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":40445,   "ctx":"TopologyVersionObserver","msg":"Started TopologyVersionObserver"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-05-11T14:23:01.626+08:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":23015,   "ctx":"listener","msg":"Listening on","attr":{"address":"/tmp/mongodb-30000.sock"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-05-11T14:23:01.626+08:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":23015,   "ctx":"listener","msg":"Listening on","attr":{"address":"0.0.0.0"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-05-11T14:23:01.626+08:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":23016,   "ctx":"listener","msg":"Waiting for connections","attr":{"port":30000,"ssl":"off"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-05-11T14:23:01.783+08:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"-",        "id":4939300, "ctx":"monitoring-keys-for-HMAC","msg":"Failed to refresh key cache","attr":{"error":"NotYetInitialized: Cannot use non-local read concern until replica set is finished initializing.","nextWakeupMillis":400}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-05-11T14:23:02.184+08:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"-",        "id":4939300, "ctx":"monitoring-keys-for-HMAC","msg":"Failed to refresh key cache","attr":{"error":"NotYetInitialized: Cannot use non-local read concern until replica set is finished initializing.","nextWakeupMillis":600}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-05-11T14:23:02.800+08:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"-",        "id":4939300, "ctx":"monitoring-keys-for-HMAC","msg":"Failed to refresh key cache","attr":{"error":"NotYetInitialized: Cannot use non-local read concern until replica set is finished initializing.","nextWakeupMillis":800}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-05-11T14:23:03.601+08:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"-",        "id":4939300, "ctx":"monitoring-keys-for-HMAC","msg":"Failed to refresh key cache","attr":{"error":"NotYetInitialized: Cannot use non-local read concern until replica set is finished initializing.","nextWakeupMillis":1000}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-05-11T14:23:04.603+08:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"-",        "id":4939300, "ctx":"monitoring-keys-for-HMAC","msg":"Failed to refresh key cache","attr":{"error":"NotYetInitialized: Cannot use non-local read concern until replica set is finished initializing.","nextWakeupMillis":1200}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-05-11T14:23:05.804+08:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"-",        "id":4939300, "ctx":"monitoring-keys-for-HMAC","msg":"Failed to refresh key cache","attr":{"error":"NotYetInitialized: Cannot use non-local read concern until replica set is finished initializing.","nextWakeupMillis":1400}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-05-11T14:23:07.206+08:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"-",        "id":4939300, "ctx":"monitoring-keys-for-HMAC","msg":"Failed to refresh key cache","attr":{"error":"NotYetInitialized: Cannot use non-local read concern until replica set is finished initializing.","nextWakeupMillis":1600}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-05-11T14:23:08.808+08:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"-",        "id":4939300, "ctx":"monitoring-keys-for-HMAC","msg":"Failed to refresh key cache","attr":{"error":"NotYetInitialized: Cannot use non-local read concern until replica set is finished initializing.","nextWakeupMillis":1800}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-05-11T14:23:10.617+08:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"-",        "id":4939300, "ctx":"monitoring-keys-for-HMAC","msg":"Failed to refresh key cache","attr":{"error":"NotYetInitialized: Cannot use non-local read concern until replica set is finished initializing.","nextWakeupMillis":2000}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-05-11T14:23:12.620+08:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"-",        "id":4939300, "ctx":"monitoring-keys-for-HMAC","msg":"Failed to refresh key cache","attr":{"error":"NotYetInitialized: Cannot use non-local read concern until replica set is finished initializing.","nextWakeupMillis":2200}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-05-11T14:23:14.822+08:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"-",        "id":4939300, "ctx":"monitoring-keys-for-HMAC","msg":"Failed to refresh key cache","attr":{"error":"NotYetInitialized: Cannot use non-local read concern until replica set is finished initializing.","nextWakeupMillis":2400}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-05-11T14:23:17.226+08:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"-",        "id":4939300, "ctx":"monitoring-keys-for-HMAC","msg":"Failed to refresh key cache","attr":{"error":"NotYetInitialized: Cannot use non-local read concern until replica set is finished initializing.","nextWakeupMillis":2600}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-05-11T14:23:19.829+08:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"-",        "id":4939300, "ctx":"monitoring-keys-for-HMAC","msg":"Failed to refresh key cache","attr":{"error":"NotYetInitialized: Cannot use non-local read concern until replica set is finished initializing.","nextWakeupMillis":2800}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-05-11T14:23:22.632+08:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"-",        "id":4939300, "ctx":"monitoring-keys-for-HMAC","msg":"Failed to refresh key cache","attr":{"error":"NotYetInitialized: Cannot use non-local read concern until replica set is finished initializing.","nextWakeupMillis":3000}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-05-11T14:23:25.636+08:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"-",        "id":4939300, "ctx":"monitoring-keys-for-HMAC","msg":"Failed to refresh key cache","attr":{"error":"NotYetInitialized: Cannot use non-local read concern until replica set is finished initializing.","nextWakeupMillis":3200}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-05-11T14:23:28.838+08:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"-",        "id":4939300, "ctx":"monitoring-keys-for-HMAC","msg":"Failed to refresh key cache","attr":{"error":"NotYetInitialized: Cannot use non-local read concern until replica set is finished initializing.","nextWakeupMillis":3400}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-05-11T14:23:32.242+08:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"-",        "id":4939300, "ctx":"monitoring-keys-for-HMAC","msg":"Failed to refresh key cache","attr":{"error":"NotYetInitialized: Cannot use non-local read concern until replica set is finished initializing.","nextWakeupMillis":3600}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-05-11T14:23:35.846+08:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"-",        "id":4939300, "ctx":"monitoring-keys-for-HMAC","msg":"Failed to refresh key cache","attr":{"error":"NotYetInitialized: Cannot use non-local read concern until replica set is finished initializing.","nextWakeupMillis":3800}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-05-11T14:23:39.650+08:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"-",        "id":4939300, "ctx":"monitoring-keys-for-HMAC","msg":"Failed to refresh key cache","attr":{"error":"NotYetInitialized: Cannot use non-local read concern until replica set is finished initializing.","nextWakeupMillis":4000}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-05-11T14:23:43.661+08:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"-",        "id":4939300, "ctx":"monitoring-keys-for-HMAC","msg":"Failed to refresh key cache","attr":{"error":"NotYetInitialized: Cannot use non-local read concern until replica set is finished initializing.","nextWakeupMillis":4200}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-05-11T14:23:47.866+08:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"-",        "id":4939300, "ctx":"monitoring-keys-for-HMAC","msg":"Failed to refresh key cache","attr":{"error":"NotYetInitialized: Cannot use non-local read concern until replica set is finished initializing.","nextWakeupMillis":4400}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-05-11T14:23:52.284+08:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"-",        "id":4939300, "ctx":"monitoring-keys-for-HMAC","msg":"Failed to refresh key cache","attr":{"error":"NotYetInitialized: Cannot use non-local read concern until replica set is finished initializing.","nextWakeupMillis":4600}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-05-11T14:23:56.886+08:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"-",        "id":4939300, "ctx":"monitoring-keys-for-HMAC","msg":"Failed to refresh key cache","attr":{"error":"NotYetInitialized: Cannot use non-local read concern until replica set is finished initializing.","nextWakeupMillis":4800}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-05-11T14:24:01.550+08:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22430,   "ctx":"Checkpointer","msg":"WiredTiger message","attr":{"message":"[1652250241:550656][876978:0x7fcd51201700], WT_SESSION.checkpoint: [WT_VERB_CHECKPOINT_PROGRESS] saving checkpoint snapshot min: 3, snapshot max: 3 snapshot count: 0, oldest timestamp: (0, 0) , meta checkpoint timestamp: (0, 0) base write gen: 443"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-05-11T14:24:01.691+08:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"-",        "id":4939300, "ctx":"monitoring-keys-for-HMAC","msg":"Failed to refresh key cache","attr":{"error":"NotYetInitialized: Cannot use non-local read concern until replica set is finished initializing.","nextWakeupMillis":5000}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-05-11T14:24:06.695+08:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"-",        "id":4939300, "ctx":"monitoring-keys-for-HMAC","msg":"Failed to refresh key cache","attr":{"error":"NotYetInitialized: Cannot use non-local read concern until replica set is finished initializing.","nextWakeupMillis":5200}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-05-11T14:24:11.905+08:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"-",        "id":4939300, "ctx":"monitoring-keys-for-HMAC","msg":"Failed to refresh key cache","attr":{"error":"NotYetInitialized: Cannot use non-local read concern until replica set is finished initializing.","nextWakeupMillis":5400}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-05-11T14:24:17.321+08:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"-",        "id":4939300, "ctx":"monitoring-keys-for-HMAC","msg":"Failed to refresh key cache","attr":{"error":"NotYetInitialized: Cannot use non-local read concern until replica set is finished initializing.","nextWakeupMillis":5600}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-05-11T14:24:22.927+08:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"-",        "id":4939300, "ctx":"monitoring-keys-for-HMAC","msg":"Failed to refresh key cache","attr":{"error":"NotYetInitialized: Cannot use non-local read concern until replica set is finished initializing.","nextWakeupMillis":5800}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-05-11T14:24:28.733+08:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"-",        "id":4939300, "ctx":"monitoring-keys-for-HMAC","msg":"Failed to refresh key cache","attr":{"error":"NotYetInitialized: Cannot use non-local read concern until replica set is finished initializing.","nextWakeupMillis":6000}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-05-11T14:24:34.740+08:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"-",        "id":4939300, "ctx":"monitoring-keys-for-HMAC","msg":"Failed to refresh key cache","attr":{"error":"NotYetInitialized: Cannot use non-local read concern until replica set is finished initializing.","nextWakeupMillis":6200}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-05-11T14:24:40.945+08:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"-",        "id":4939300, "ctx":"monitoring-keys-for-HMAC","msg":"Failed to refresh key cache","attr":{"error":"NotYetInitialized: Cannot use non-local read concern until replica set is finished initializing.","nextWakeupMillis":6400}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-05-11T14:24:47.367+08:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"-",        "id":4939300, "ctx":"monitoring-keys-for-HMAC","msg":"Failed to refresh key cache","attr":{"error":"NotYetInitialized: Cannot use non-local read concern until replica set is finished initializing.","nextWakeupMillis":6600}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-05-11T14:24:53.969+08:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"-",        "id":4939300, "ctx":"monitoring-keys-for-HMAC","msg":"Failed to refresh key cache","attr":{"error":"NotYetInitialized: Cannot use non-local read concern until replica set is finished initializing.","nextWakeupMillis":6800}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-05-11T14:25:00.778+08:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"-",        "id":4939300, "ctx":"monitoring-keys-for-HMAC","msg":"Failed to refresh key cache","attr":{"error":"NotYetInitialized: Cannot use non-local read concern until replica set is finished initializing.","nextWakeupMillis":7000}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-05-11T14:25:01.605+08:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22430,   "ctx":"Checkpointer","msg":"WiredTiger message","attr":{"message":"[1652250301:605334][876978:0x7fcd51201700], WT_SESSION.checkpoint: [WT_VERB_CHECKPOINT_PROGRESS] saving checkpoint snapshot min: 6, snapshot max: 6 snapshot count: 0, oldest timestamp: (0, 0) , meta checkpoint timestamp: (0, 0) base write gen: 443"}}
```

Below is the replica config file on Node1

```
replicaset01:PRIMARY> rs.conf()
{
        "_id" : "replicaset01",
        "version" : 290977,
        "term" : 10,
        "members" : [
                {
                        "_id" : 0,
                        "host" : "192.168.30.20:27017",
                        "arbiterOnly" : false,
                        "buildIndexes" : true,
                        "hidden" : false,
                        "priority" : 2,
                        "tags" : {

                        },
                        "secondaryDelaySecs" : NumberLong(0),
                        "votes" : 1
                },
                {
                        "_id" : 1,
                        "host" : "192.168.70.20:27017",
                        "arbiterOnly" : false,
                        "buildIndexes" : true,
                        "hidden" : false,
                        "priority" : 1,
                        "tags" : {

                        },
                        "secondaryDelaySecs" : NumberLong(0),
                        "votes" : 1
                }
        ],
        "protocolVersion" : NumberLong(1),
        "writeConcernMajorityJournalDefault" : true,
        "settings" : {
                "chainingAllowed" : true,
                "heartbeatIntervalMillis" : 2000,
                "heartbeatTimeoutSecs" : 10,
                "electionTimeoutMillis" : 10000,
                "catchUpTimeoutMillis" : -1,
                "catchUpTakeoverDelayMillis" : 30000,
                "getLastErrorModes" : {

                },
                "getLastErrorDefaults" : {
                        "w" : 1,
                        "wtimeout" : 0
                },
                "replicaSetId" : ObjectId("6257e4fb2862cabac198c12c")
        }
}
```

And below is the freezing of mongo, I have awaited for more than 20 mins, add as replication run almost immediately but not add as Arbiter.
[image]

Comment: I prefer to use [config files](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/configuration-options/) instead of command line options. Perhaps a mongod service is already installed and running on 192.168.60.20 and it also uses dbPath `/var/lib/mongo/data`. Perhaps your firewall blocks port 30000 (default port 27017 works as well)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You follow better [Deploy a Replica Set](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/deploy-replica-set/) and [Add an Arbiter to Replica Set](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/add-replica-set-arbiter/) If you like to convert an existing deployment then follow [Convert a Standalone to a Replica Set](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/convert-standalone-to-replica-set/)

The reference you linked in your question will not work, it has several faults:

MongoDB configuration files use the YAML format. Plain edits like

```
# vi /etc/mongod.conf
replSet = prodRepl
```

do not work. Perhaps this was different in 2014/2016 when the page was written.

He enables authentication (which is really honorably), however he starts the arbiter service `nohup mongod --port 30000 --dbpath /var/lib/mongo/data --replSet replicaset01 --bind_ip_all` without authentication (i.e. `--auth and --keyFile` are missing).

Apart from that, you would need to start the Arbiter every time you boot the machine. Why not simply edit the existing configuration file `/etc/mongod.conf`?

Answer (score -1):

I have finally fixed this stuff.

Instead of SSH into the server and using its SSH's mongo shell, I changed to Mongo Compass and use their shell.

Right immediately the error pops up.